# Writing to existing file

Tags: go, logrus

here is the code:

```golang
tmp, _ := os.OpenFile(filepath.Join(this.dirPath , "Log_"+time.Now().Format(conf.FormatFile())), os.O_CREATE|os.O_WRONLY, os.ModePerm)
logrus.SetOutput(tmp)
```

it works, but if the program is run again and a file with the same name already exists, writing to it does not occur, there are no errors, logs are not written and that’s it. It seems to me something with this os.ModePerm flag.

The problem is repeated only on linux.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably should use `os.O_APPEND` flag.

```
tmp, _ := os.OpenFile(
  filepath.Join(this.dirPath, "Log_"+time.Now().Format(conf.FormatFile())), 
  os.O_APPEND|os.O_WRONLY, 
  os.ModePerm,
)
```

https://godoc.org/os#pkg-constants

Comment: I have to use the condition, if the file exists, then O_APPEND, otherwise O_CREATE?

Comment: I think you should use someting like this `os.O_APPEND | os.O_CREATE | os.O_WRONLY`